# How to connect to another docker service from one docker service in a docker swarm cluster?

Tags: api, docker, service, microservices, docker-swarm

In the docker swarm cluster, launched two services:

- sv_web
- sv_api

The stack deploy file of web is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: XXX/sv_web:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Deploy:

```
docker stack deploy -c ~/docker-compose-web.yml sv
```

The stack deploy file of api is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: XXX/sv_api:latest
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Deploy:

```
docker stack deploy -c ~/docker-compose-api.yml sv
```

Now want to connect `sv_api` service inside the `sv_web` application. Tried to write:

```
api_server = "sv_api:81"
```

But can't connect the `sv_api` service after deploying it. If use the real IP of the host in the cluster, it can be found: `[HOST]:81`.

So how to connect to the API service from web service in this way?

Answer (score 0):

For connect you should using

> depends_on

```
services:
    some_service:
        image: link
        depends_on:
           -api
    api:
      image: link
```

More info at docs: [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config)

Comment: I have tried that. But didn't fix. I am using two files to deploy the two projects. They are in the different files. I tried both `- sv_api` and `- api` in the web deploy yaml file, the same result can't connect to `sv_api` service.

Comment: Did you get some error? Both services up? What is display docker-compose ps ?

Comment: I am using a npm lib named `http-proxy`. To connect the Api server like: `proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://mytarget.com:8080' });`. So if change the `target` address to `sv_api:81`. It will fail because that's not a http address.

Comment: Run container and ckeck it ip address container. Try to connect via ip address container.